# Using SelectedItem value from ComboBox to populate additional TextBoxes

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I'm working on a WPF application that contains a model for monetary currencies. Each currency consists of:

- `String Name`
- `SortedDictionary<String, Double> PurchaseInstruments`
- `SortedDictionary<String, Double> SaleInstruments`

Example of a purchase instrument pair would be "cash" => 5.00

In my XAML I have the following excerpt:

```xml
<ComboBox Name="cmbbx" Height="20" Width="60" Grid.Column="1" 
          ItemsSource="{Binding Path=InstrumentTypes}" 
          SelectedItem="{Binding CurrencyInstrument}" 
          SelectedValuePath="Key" DisplayMemberPath="Key" 
          IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="False" Selected="cmbbx_Selected">
</ComboBox>
<TextBlock Name="purchase_price" Grid.Column="2" 
           Text="{PurchaseInstruments[SelectedValue]}"/>
<TextBlock Grid.Column="3" Text="{SaleInstruments[SelectedValue]}"/>
```

In the text values for the textblocks, I've added the values I would like to have there although I know the code doesn't work. How can I use the value binded to CurrencyInstrument (value for example might be "cash") variable in my viewmodel to access the SortedDictionary PurchaseInstruments for each currency?

Desired result would be:

```
|Currency|Instrument|Purchase Price|Sale Price
|GBP     |cash      |1.12          |1.20
```

Ignore the poor formatting. 
[image]

Comment: If you use MvvM then your CurrencyInstrument(SelectedItem) property can set properties that TextBlocks use. This only works for one row. If you want that to be for a list of items then use a `Converter` that will give you ability to pull any data into the TextBlocks based on the `ComboBox` selection.

Comment: @XAMlMAX Thanks for the response but I have a followup question. I essentially want to use the value of CurrencyInstrument as a key for my PurchaseInstruments and SaleInstruments Dictionary (i.e. PurchaseInstruments[CurrencyInstrument] where string value of CurrencyInstrument is used). Can I do this in XAML or does it need to be done in the view model?

Comment: If you use `Converter` then you'll do it in code `C#`. Xaml has very limited support for expresssions, unless you use fixed value [0] or [1] this would not work. If you really really want to make it work with `[SelectedItem]` then you need to create your own collection with overriden operator. Better to use converter that has access to all that data.

Comment: @XAMlMAX Using a converter seems plausible but then in the code behind, I need to access my ViewModel to figure out what currency dictionary I need to access, which isn't straightforward and seems counter to MVVM architecture? The problem here is not so much the presentation of the data more but rather binding to a dictionary where the key is dynamically given from the user in the combobox.

Comment: Accessing vm in the code behind is fine, as long as VM doesn't have any references to UI elements. I don't understand why your currency object can't hold the currency at load?

Comment: @XAMlMAX Thanks for the help, I was always to solve the problem by refactoring my design and creating a separate CurrencyInstrument object that has properties for the prices. In the combobox, I bind the SelectedValue to that object. Then I can bind the prices to the textblocks with an expression like SelectedValue.PurchasePrice